# How can I write a function that doesn't print out uppercase words from the list?

Tags: python, list, function

I've a list ["ABC", "JAVA", "Python", "user", "CODE"] and I want the functions print out ["Python", "user"].

Here is my progress so far:

```
def no_upper(my_list : list):
    new_list = my_list
    for word in my_list:
        if word.isupper():
            my_list.remove(word)
        return new_list
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = ["ABC", "JAVA", "Python", "user", "CODE"]
    new_list = no_upper(my_list)
    print(new_list)
```

Comment: You need to enclose string literals in quotes, e.g. `"ABC"` instead of `ABC`.

Comment: You're also returning inside the loop so it will always return after the first word. Unindent return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you objective is to "remove" words written entirely in capital letters:

```
lst = ["ABC", "JAVA", "Python", "user", "CODE"]
[x for x in lst if x != x.upper()]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['Python', 'user']
```

Answer (score 3):

- Enclose your strings in quotes.
- Your function tries to modify `my_list` rather than actually building your `new_list`.  Just build the new list and return it without trying to remove the items from the input -- modifying a list you're iterating over will usually have unexpected/buggy results, and even if it worked to do that, there's no good reason to mess around with the caller's data that way.

```
>>> def no_upper(my_list: list) -> list:
...     return [word for word in my_list if not word.isupper()]
...
>>> no_upper(["ABC", "JAVA", "Python", "user", "CODE"])
['Python', 'user']
```

Comment: this answer actually explained what was wrong with original code.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a list like this:

```
my_list = ["ABC", "Java", "Python"]
```

Unless Python will `raise` an `UnboundLocalError`, since `ABC` without quotes (`''`) or double quotes (`""`) is parsed as a variable, but there's no `ABC` variable in your program.

You can also use inline syntax to solve your problem, like this:

```
def noUpper(l: list):
    return [x for x in list if not x.isupper()]
```

Comment: `x.islower()` isn't the same thing as `not x.isupper()`!

Comment: You're right, it only checks if the string has a lowercase char, right?

Comment: Nope.  Try `"Python".islower()`.

Comment: Oh, so I simply didn't understand the question: the OP doesn't want to remove "Python" from te list. I tought he only wanted the strings which were ALL lowercase. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: It's important to read the whole question -- they said specifically 'I want the functions print out ["Python", "user"].', which makes it possible to infer what behavior they want to have for mixed-case strings.  :)